# How to replace pandas column value with condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace columnb value with a mapping dictionary, but I cannot split those columns and map it and the concat everything back to same place that would be a tedious task.
Any help on this would be great.

df:

```
ColumnA   ColumB
0 Rick     3-1,4-5,9-8
1 Tim      6-3,1-2,1.3,5.8,7-9

Mapping_dict= {'3-1':'1','4-5':2,'9-8':3,
'6-3':4,'1-2':5,'1.3':6,'5.8':'7','7-9':'8'}
```

Output:

```
  ColumnA   ColumB
  0 Rick     1,2,3
  1 Tim      4,5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas apply function to map the original value with your mapping dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

Mapping_dict= {'3-1':'1','4-5':2,'9-8':3,'6-3':4,'1-2':5,'1.3':6,'5.8':'7','7-9':'8'}
d = {'ColumnA': ['Rick', 'Tim'], 'ColumB': ['3-1,4-5,9-8', '6-3,1-2,1.3,5.8,7-9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['ColumB'] = df['ColumB'].apply(lambda x: [Mapping_dict[y] for y in x.split(',')] )
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `Mapping_dict` contains all values as string you can use **[`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)** which accepts a replacement dictionary as an argument which then can be used to replace the values in `ColumB`:

```
df['ColumB'] = df['ColumB'].replace(Mapping_dict, regex=True)
```

---

```
>>> df

  ColumnA     ColumB
0    Rick      1,2,3
1     Tim  4,5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ColumnA=['Rick','Tim']  
ColumnB=['3-1,4-5,9-8','6-3,1-2,1.3,5.8,7-9']

df=pd.DataFrame({'columnA':ColumnA,'columnB':ColumnB})

Mapping_dict= {'3-1':'1','4-5':2,'9-8':3,'6-3':4,'1-2':5,'1.3':6,'5.8':'7','7-9':'8'}

def lookup(columnString):
    elements=columnString.split(",")
    mylist=[str(Mapping_dict[element]) for element in elements]
    retVal=",".join(mylist)
    return retVal

df['columnB']=df['columnB'].apply(lambda x: lookup(x))
print(df)
output:

  columnA    columnB
0    Rick      1,2,3
1     Tim  4,5,6,7,8
```